# How to configure wpa_supplicant.conf for NetworkManager WiFi proper management?

Tags: wireless-networking, networkmanager, wpa-supplicant

I have NetworkManager installed on Wrap7 board(which runs embedded Linux distro), but NetworkManager does not detect WiFi interface with a default content of  wpa_supplicant.conf. Here is wpa_supplicant.conf default content:

```
root@imx7s-warp-mbl:~# cat /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ctrl_interface_group=0
update_config=1

network={
        key_mgmt=NONE
}
```

If I update wpa_supplicant.conf file manually with the properties (ssid, wep_key0 ...) of the particular WiFi network, Network manager starts to detect wifi networks... But this is an unacceptable solution of course. I need to allow NetworkManager to do this function.

So the question, **how should I change the default content of the wpa_supplicant.conf file in order to allow NetworkManager to manage wifi connections?**

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't configure it *at all*. The only instance of wpa_supplicant that should be running is:

```
/usr/bin/wpa_supplicant -u
```

This is usually launched automatically by NetworkManager (via dbus-daemon). It ignores the conf file, does not create the traditional control interface, and only accepts configuration via D-Bus.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution that worked for me. Few steps:

1. Change /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf to contain the following content:

   `ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
   ctrl_interface_group=0
   update_config=0`

   Block "network={...}" should be removed, and also, `update_config` should be set to 0.
2. NetworkManager does not manage any interface defined in /etc/network/interfaces default (unmanaged devices means NetworkManager doesn't handle those network devices). In order to allow to NetworkManager to manage Wi-Fi interface, **comment out the `Wireless interfaces` block in `/etc/network/interfaces`**.
3. Create the /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf with the following content:

   `[main]
   plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
   [ifupdown]
   managed=**true**`
4. Reboot the machine
5. After reboot, run NetworkManager service

   `NetworkManager`

From this point, networkmanager can manage Wi-Fi connections.

Answer (score 0):

This fix worked for me on my pi4 after I'd run 'raspi-config' and it borked my wifi settings. Network manager just could not connect. AP seen, but the correct passkey was rejected.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1080430)